# How do you expand this frobenius form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I'm trying to expand this Frobenius form $||C \circ (A-XB)||_F^2$ (here $\circ$ is the Hadamard point-wise multiplication). I want to find the minimum value with respect to X.

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial X}||C \circ (A-XB)||_F^2 = 0$$

I've being trying to develop using the fact that the Frobenius form is $||A||_F^2=trace(AA^*)$ but the Hadamard product is always on my way.

How would you approach this?

Comment: You can put $g(X)=C\circ (A-XB)$ where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product, and use the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

Given $f = \|M\|_F^2 = M:M$, the differential is  $\,\,df=2M:dM$

Substituting $M=C\circ(A-XB)$, we have
$$ \eqalign {
  df &= 2(C\circ(A-XB)) : d(C\circ (A-XB)) \cr
     &= -2(C\circ(A-XB)) : C\circ dX\,B \cr
     &= -2(C\circ(A-XB)\circ C) : dX\,B \cr
     &= -2(C\circ(A-XB)\circ C)B^T : dX \cr
     &= \bigg(\frac {\partial f} {\partial X}\bigg) : dX \cr
} $$
Setting the derivative to zero yields
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial X} &= 0 = -2\,(C\circ(A-XB)\circ C)B^T \cr
 (XB\circ C\circ C)B^T&= (A\circ C\circ C)B^T \cr
} $$
Now what is the best way to solve for $X$?

Comment: Hi greg, Did you known how the solve this for X? I have the same question about this.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670377/what-is-close-form-solution-using-als-algorithm-to-optimize-this-objective-funct      Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the chain rule. $$\partial (\mathbf{X} \circ\mathbf{Y}) = \partial \mathbf{X} \circ \mathbf{Y}  + \mathbf{X} \circ \partial  \mathbf{Y} $$

Also, the fact that $$||\mathbf{A}||_2^2 = trace(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A})$$

Look the following reference for matrix calculus it has all the stuff you would need.

Matrix Cookbook:
[http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf][1]